# Woocommerce - get daily sales meta

Tags: php, woocommerce-offtopic, sql

I am writing custom woocommerce plugin.

Does woocommerce has any daily sales report of each product?

I know, that get_post_meta can show total sales of certain product, but I need to show sales of each product each day. So for example - Product A was bought 37 times at 27-03-2020, and then, I need to retrive this data .

No idea how to do it, maybe somehow with ACF update_field function? 
https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/update_field/

Thanks,

Wojtek

Answer (score 0):

The question that you posted is unfortunately not all that specific but take a look at Woocommerce analytics.

Otherwise there are 2 ways to do this on your own. 
1. Query all the orders for day X and count the qty of a specific product.
2. Update the products sold after each purchase. Perhaps to a custom db table or somewhere else

Comment: Thank you, to be more precise - the plugin that I am working on will be used on local bakery, that sells their products online. Product A ordered on monday, will be produced on tuesday, and it will be taken from tuesday stock. So i need to have two values - stock from current day, and stock from day before, so i could subtract him

Comment: My suggestion, considering the new information, is that you store the stock from the products bought the day before in a product meta field. As for the stock calculation it all depends on when do you need to display live stock values. You can recalculate it once par day or for every order (plus the recalculation from yesterday 1x per day).

Comment: Yes, but these are only theoretical considerations, I need a specific method available in woocommerce 3.0+ that will allow me to do this. Preferably snippet, or a reference to codex.